# JSON schema validator - validate one property based on another property in different part of schema

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, ajv

I have open api schema in which I want to validate that

1. If the `oauth2` flow in the `components` section contains the `tokenUrl` in `string` format then `url` in the `servers` section should have `https:` in the url value.
2. If the `tokenUrl` is not present then it should do nothing

is there any way this is possible with JSON schema validator?

Below is the schema for reference

```
{  
    "servers": [
        {
            "url": "http://my.api.server.com/",
            "description": "API server"
        }
    ], 
    "components": {
        "securitySchemes": {
            "OAuth2": {
                "type": "oauth2",
                "flows": {
                    "authorizationCode": {
                        "scopes": {
                            "write": "modify objects in your account",
                            "read": "read objects in your account"
                        },
                        "authorizationUrl": "https://example.com/oauth/authorize",
                        "tokenUrl": "https://example.com/oauth/token" 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "security": [
        {
        "OAuth2": [
                "write",
                "read"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to achieve this type of validation. Below is the schema that helps you validate the same

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "servers": {},
    "components": {}
  },
  "if": {
    "properties": {
      "components": {
        "properties": {
          "securitySchemes": {
            "type": "object",
            "patternProperties": {
              "^[a-zA-Z0-9\\.\\-_]+$": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "flows": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                      "tokenUrl": {
                        "const": true
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "then": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "servers": {
        "items": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "url": {
              "type": "string",
              "pattern": "https://"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`if - then` is used to set up conditional relation between components `tokenUrl` property and servers `url` property. Here

```
{
    "tokenUrl": {
        "const": true
    }
}
```

means that `tokenUrl` should be present in the `components` object, then whatever rule is defined in `then` blocks takes effect. Here below schema will validate the `url` pattern to be `https` only

```
{
    "url": {
        "type": "string",
        "pattern": "https://"
    }
}
```

Comment: Here we can check the schema validation - https://jsonschema.dev/s/GRLKK